# How can I set image location correctly in Swift?

Tags: swift, autolayout, swrevealviewcontroller

In my app, I am using SWRevealViewController. Currently everything is working OK except for the menu image position.I set up the menu button programatically. Now I need to put it to the correct place.It also needs to work in all screen sizes and needs to be at the same place.
I set up the menu button like this

```
    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {


    let image = UIImage(named: "reveal-icon@2x.png")

    tabBarController?.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style:
        UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self.revealViewController(), action: Selector("revealToggle:"))
    tabBarController?.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.image = image


}
```

and here is the result

[image: ScreenShot]

---

How do I fix it? I think I need to do it programatically...
And here is the overall layout of my storyboard file.

[image: ScreenShot2]

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: When using `UITabBarController`s and `UINavigationController`s together, the `UITabBarController` should come first, and each item in the `UITabBarController` should have its own `UINavigationController` stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be happening because you are initializing the UIBarButtonItem with a title. Initialize it with something like this:

```
let img = UIImage(named: "reveal-icon@2x.png")!.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal)
let leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: img, style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self.revealViewController(), action: Selector("revealToggle:"))
tabBarController?.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftBarButtonItem
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.It works perfect apart from one drawback and that is, now the menu image is in grey, not blue. I do not know what caused it...I would be glad if you could tell me.Thanks again

Comment: try initializing the UIImage without the RenderingMode `let img = UIImage(named: "reveal-icon@2x.png")`